# Writing an expandable conditional column formula

Tags: calculated-column

```
=ModuleNum&"."&SectionNum&"."&Sub1_SectionNum&"."&Sub2_SectionNum&"."&Sub3_SectionNum&"."&Sub4_SectionNum&"."&Sub5_SectionNum&"."&Sub6_SectionNum


IF SectionNum >= 0
THEN &"."&Sub1_SectionNum

IF Sub1_SectionNum != Null
THEN &"."&Sub2_SectionNum

IF Sub2_SectionNum != Null
THEN &"."&Sub3_SectionNum

IF Sub3_SectionNum != Null
THEN &"."&Sub4_SectionNum

IF Sub4_SectionNum != Null
THEN &"."&Sub5_SectionNum

IF Sub5_SectionNum != Null
THEN &"."&Sub6_SectionNum
```

I have a formula like the one above, and a lot of times it is giving me results like "10.0....." instead of what I'd like 10.0 or 2.4.5.6.1.3.7.1. I would like to make it conditional to handle both cases and I think this will require a nested conditional formula. I need some assistance with the nesting.

For example, I was able to write the formula

```
=ModuleNum&"."&IF(SectionNum>=0,SectionNum,"F")&"."&IF(Sub1_SectionNum>0,Sub1_SectionNum,"F")&"."&IF(Sub2_SectionNum>0,Sub2_SectionNum,"F")&"."&IF(Sub3_SectionNum>0,Sub3_SectionNum,"F")&"."&IF(Sub4_SectionNum>0,Sub4_SectionNum,"F")&"."&IF(Sub5_SectionNum>0,Sub5_SectionNum,"F")&"."&IF(Sub6_SectionNum>0,Sub6_SectionNum,"F")
```

which adds the conditional portion, but you will see that if the condition is not greater than 0, it will show .F instead of nothing. I would like for if the condition is not greater than 0 for the statement to stop evaluating.

I think I want something like this,

```
=ModuleNum & IF(SectionNum>=0,&"."&SectionNum,"F")
```

But I can't seem to get it to evaluate in my xlsx

Much Appreciated!

Comment: Are the SectionNums you want to ignore always blank? Or do you want 10.0.0.0.0.0.0 to evaluate to 10?

Comment: Only ModuleNum and SectionNum are required, so if ModuleNum is 2 and SectionNum is 0, I'd like it to evalulate to 2.0.

Sub#_SectionNums can be blank.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So @Aron Foster and I took this off-stack, and I wanted to share what the solution that he ended up coming up with to solve my issue.

```
=ModuleNum& IF(COUNTA(SectionNum),"."&SectionNum& IF(Sub1_SectionNum>0,"."&Sub1_SectionNum&IF(Sub2_SectionNum>0,"."&Sub2_SectionNum& IF(Sub3_SectionNum>0,"."&Sub3_SectionNum& IF(Sub4_SectionNum>0,"."&Sub4_SectionNum& IF(Sub5_SectionNum>0,"."&Sub5_SectionNum& IF(Sub6_SectionNum>0,"."&Sub6_SectionNum,""),""),""),""),""),""),"")
```

*Important to note: There is a maximum of 8 IF statements that can be used

Many Thanks @Aron Foster!

Answer (score 0):

This was my first instinct:

```
x = SectionNum&"."&Sub1_SectionNum&"."&Sub2_SectionNum&"."&Sub3_SectionNum&"."&Sub4_SectionNum&"."&Sub5_SectionNum&"."&Sub6_SectionNum
y = SectionNum,Sub1_SectionNum,Sub2_SectionNum,Sub3_SectionNum,Sub4_SectionNum,Sub5_SectionNum,Sub6_SectionNum
z = number of section/subsection levels, in this case 7
Formula:
  =ModuleNum&"."&LEFT(x,LEN(x)+COUNT(y)-z)
```

But I think your "for example" formula was actually really close to working, being correct, and better than my first instinct. Here it is fixed:

```
=ModuleNum&IF(COUNTA(SectionNum),"."&SectionNum,"")&IF(COUNTA(Sub1_SectionNum),"."&Sub1_SectionNum,"")&IF(COUNTA(Sub2_SectionNum),"."&Sub2_SectionNum,"")&IF(COUNTA(Sub3_SectionNum),"."&Sub3_SectionNum,"")&IF(COUNTA(Sub4_SectionNum),"."&Sub4_SectionNum,"")&IF(COUNTA(Sub5_SectionNum),"."&Sub5_SectionNum,"")&IF(COUNTA(Sub6_SectionNum),"."&Sub6_SectionNum,"")
```

Both of these assume that all columns you want to leave out will be blank. COUNTA will allow text and special characters; use COUNT if you only want numbers. If they're number columns, then it doesn't matter.

Here is the new formula that solves your problem with the following additional requirements: Any sub section numbers will be ignored if they are zero or are after a sub section with zero. SectionNum can be zero. Note that SharePoint only allows 8 levels of nesting, so you could add a Sub7_SectionNum but then not a Sub8_SectionNum.

```
=ModuleNum&IF(COUNTA(SectionNum),"."&SectionNum&IF(Sub1_SectionNum>0,"."&Sub1_SectionNum&IF(Sub2_SectionNum>0,"."&Sub2_SectionNum&IF(Sub3_SectionNum>0,"."&Sub3_SectionNum&IF(Sub4_SectionNum>0,"."&Sub4_SectionNum&IF(Sub5_SectionNum>0,"."&Sub5_SectionNum&IF(Sub6_SectionNum>0,"."&Sub6_SectionNum,""),""),""),""),""),""),"")
```

Comment: I haven't tried your first instinct, but after evaluating your second, I can say that it is not quite what I am looking for. The formula should stop evaluating when it reaches a 0, and the second formula does not do that. I wish there was a way I could post an attachment so I could show you my xlsx of what I mean.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean about "stop evaluating when it reaches a 0"? So if ModuleNum = 10, SectionNum = 0 and Sub1_SectionNum is 5, you want if to display 10.0? You could use Dropbox or SkyDrive or Mega to host your example xlsx.

Comment: Aron,
There wouldn't be a 10.0.5. These are chapter numbers that we call Modules... If that helps how you think of things. Anyways, here's a link to my spreadsheet, let me know if there are issues accessing it.
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6Zl61x54NhySTNyZ0dQazZsOGM/edit?usp=sharing